# how to count the number of specific lines between time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that contains two columns: time and source and I want to count 192.168.1.128 between each second

```
I have this:


                 Time           Source
  2022-11-27 09:19:27    192.168.1.128
  2022-11-27 09:19:27    152.199.19.161
  2022-11-27 09:19:27    192.168.1.128
  2022-11-27 09:19:27    192.168.1.128
  2022-11-27 09:19:28    142.250.186.67
  2022-11-27 09:19:29    192.168.1.128
  2022-11-27 09:19:29    192.168.1.128
  2022-11-27 09:19:30    192.168.1.128
  2022-11-27 09:19:30    142.250.186.67


and trying to get it like this:

                 Time       Count 
  2022-11-27 09:19:27           3
  2022-11-27 09:19:28           0
  2022-11-27 09:19:29           2
  2022-11-27 09:19:30           1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
df['Source'].eq('192.168.1.128').groupby(df['Time']).count().reset_index()
```